# If the product $v(t)x(t)$ tends to zero, but $v(t)$ does not have a limit, must $x(t)$ tend to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given: two continuous, bounded function $v(t),x(t)$, $v(t)$ doesn't have a limit, $\lim_{t\to\infty}v(t)x(t)=0$. We want to conclude that:
$\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$. Could somebody give a rigorous proof using the definition of limits? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such proof, because the statement is not true.

**Counterexample:** define the periodic function
$$
f(t) = \max\{\sin( \pi t),0\} = 
\begin{cases}
\sin (\pi t) & t \in [2n,2n+1]\\
0 & t \in (2n+1,2n+2)
\end{cases}\quad n \in \Bbb Z
$$
Define $v(t) = f(t);$ $x(t) = f(t + 1).$

Comment: Thanks!! May I ask what kind of conditions should $v(t)$ satisfy to make $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$? Thanks anyway!!

Comment: If $v$ is continuous, we would have to have $|v(t)| \geq a$ for some $a > 0$ for all values of $t>t_0$ (for some $t_0$).  So yes, a lower bound for the magnitude would work.

Comment: Yes! If $v(t)\ngeq a>0$ , then during some time interval $[t_0,t_0+T]$ $v(t)$ might tend to 0. This moment $x(t)$ has got a chance to escape from 0. Thus we need the lower bound of $v(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

You need more conditions on $x(t)$ and $v(t)$.

Let $x(t) = |\sin(\pi t)|+\sin(\pi t)$ and $v(t) = |\sin(\pi t)|-\sin(\pi t)$.

Then, $x(t)v(t) = |\sin(\pi t)|^2 - \sin(\pi t)^2 = 0$ for all $t$, and thus, $\displaystyle\lim_{t \to \infty}x(t)v(t) = 0$.

However, neither $x(t)$ not $v(t)$ have a limit as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and example! I should add more conditions on $x(t)$ and $v(t)$. May I ask if I want $\lim_{t\to\infty}x(t)=0$, what condition should $v(t)$ satisfy? Lower bounded or something?